# good numerical solution for LDA transformation

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I'm computing an LDA (linear discriminant analysis) transform, for an application I'm working on, and I've been following these [notes](http://www.ed.uiuc.edu/courses/EdPsy494/lectures/DiscriminantAnalysis-online.pdf) (starting at page 36, especially slide 47 in green).

I'm doing this in Python (with numpy and scipy), and this is what I have come up with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm
...
sw_inv_sqrt = np.linalg.inv(sqrtm(self.sigma_within))
self.d, self.v = np.linalg.eig(
    np.dot(
        np.dot(sw_inv_sqrt, self.sigma_between),
        sw_inv_sqrt
        ))
self.v = np.dot(sw_inv_sqrt, self.v)
```

I know that this implementation is correct as I have compared it to others.  My concern is whether this is **good** solution in the **numerical sense**.  In comparing my solution to others, they match only to about 6 decimal places.  Is there a better way to do this numerically?

Comment: This is in essence a mathematical question -- you are asking for a numerical *method*, not for its *implementation*.  You might be better off asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Do you actually need more than 6 decimal places precision ? (I'd consider that pretty good actually). Are the other solutions you refer to also implemented in python ? Why do you suspect that the others' solutions are numerically better than yours (as far as I remember is this the standard way to calculate the projection vector of Fisher's linear discriminant analysis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) ? You could also ask on stats.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @Sven: I don't necessarily agree. Implementation details may introduce *roundoff error*, which is different from *truncation error* which is by essence mathematical. Moreover, with all the respect I owe to the folks at math.stackexchange, I think there are better numericists here than there.

Answer (score 2):

Try `eigh` instead of `eig`. Since Sigma^{-1/2} B_0 Sigma^{1/2} is symmetric, use an adapted routine.

Also, beware of using the right algorithm when computing B_0. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Two-pass_algorithm for a simpler case (that you can adapt here).

Comment: Thanks, this is a good tip, but it didn't change my results by much...  Might be that Andre is right, and that different platforms cause the differences.

Comment: In LAPACK (at least Intel MKL version) there is an option to compute the eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix with high accuracy. The method is far from trivial though. If you are willing to rewrite your code in C or Fortran, you can make use of it.